# Discord Python Rewrite - Broadcast

Tags: discord, discord.py

Is it possible to make the bot sends 1 message on every server that the bot is in without sending the message to every channel? I have a working code but it sends to all channel

```
@client.command()
async def broadcast(ctx, *, message):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            
            if guild.name == ctx.author.guild.name:
                pass

            else:
                try:
                    await channel.send(message)
                    await ctx.send(
                        'Sent to {} (ID: {}, Owner: {}#{} With {} Members)'.format(
                            guild.name,
                            guild.id,
                            guild.owner.name,
                            guild.owner.discriminator,
                            guild.member_count
                            ))

                except:
                await ctx.send(
                    'Could not send at {} (Channel ID: {}). (Owner: {}#{})'.format(
                        guild.name,
                        channel.id,
                        guild.owner.name,
                        guild.owner.discriminator,
                        ))
                    return

                else:
                    break
please help
```

Comment: The problem with something like this is there's no easy way to control what channel you actually send to. You could pop 1 channel off the iterator instead of looping, or something like that, but for all intents it would be a random channel per guild. The much cleaner option would be to let guilds use a command to specify what channel they want to receives broadcasts in, then just loop over all those channels, but storing the channel IDs would be a large structure investment. CSV/Json read/write at easiest or Database access at hardest. Think about what you'd like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```py
for guild in client.guilds:
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="general")
    if channel != None:
       #do something
```

you could get the #general channel from each guild. That would be just one channel (Discord allows multiple channels to share names but most people won't do this, and `.get()` will return the first only, anyway).
This is much better than looping over all channels and slightly better than picking random channels but I still would consider letting guilds set their own broadcast reception channels.

Tested and it works, albeit my bot exists only in one server, I don't know if there are unknown consequences for trying to do this over 100+ servers.

Comment: tysm, i was confused on how to make it, but now i understand, Ty